Using colmap c++ code, how can i calculate the reprojection error / accuracy of the solved camera poses?
I have a colmap reconstruction that I am running in c++. I need to calculate teh accuracy (by using the point reprojection error) for each camera pose.
I have this code to extract the poses:
struct cameraPose
{
    int camera_id;
    Eigen::Vector3d position;
    Eigen::Quaterniond quat;
    double rms_error;
    int bundle;
};

struct reconResult
{
    std::vector<cameraPose> cameras;
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> points;
};

// Function to print details of cameras, images, and 3D points
colmapFunctions::reconResult colmapFunctions::PrintReconstructionDetails(const std::shared_ptr<colmap::Reconstruction>& reconstruction_ptr) {
    // Print cameras

    colmapFunctions::reconResult results;

    std::cout << "Cameras:" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& camera_item : reconstruction_ptr->Cameras()) {

        colmapFunctions::cameraPose cam;
        const colmap::Camera& camera = camera_item.second;

        cam.camera_id = camera.CameraId();


        std::cout << "Camera ID: " << camera.CameraId() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Camera Model: " << camera.ModelName() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Width: " << camera.Width() << ", Height: " << camera.Height() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Parameters: ";
        for (const auto& param : camera.Params()) {
            std::cout << param << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    int numImages = reconstruction_ptr->Images().size();
    int numGroups = numImages / 4;


    // Print images
    std::cout << "\nImages:" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& image_item : reconstruction_ptr->Images()) {
        const colmap::Image& image = image_item.second;        

        // Only process registered images
        if (image.IsRegistered()) {
            cameraPose camera_pose;
            camera_pose.camera_id = image.CameraId();
            camera_pose.quat = image.CamFromWorld().rotation;// Quaternion rotation
            camera_pose.position = image.CamFromWorld().translation; // Translation vector

            int image_index = static_cast<int>(image.ImageId());  // Convert image_id to an index
            int group_id = image_index / numGroups; // Assign group ID (0 for first 4 images, 1 for next 4, etc.)

  

            camera_pose.bundle = group_id;
            results.cameras.push_back(camera_pose);
            std::cout << "Image ID: " << image.ImageId() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Image Name: " << image.Name() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Camera ID: " << image.CameraId() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Registered: " << (image.IsRegistered() ? "Yes" : "No") << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Group ID: " << group_id << std::endl;


        }

        

    }

} 

How can i get the error of each mage pose?
